# Android Bitmap won't compress

Tags: android, image, parse-platform, bitmap, compression

I'm trying to compress a Bitmap which is taken from either the user's gallery or camera and store it as a profile picture in a Parse Server.

The issue is the bitmap will NOT compress. The image saves perfectly fine and is useable in the database, but the file size is massive for just a profile picture.

Here's my current code:

```
//Compressing
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
profilePictureBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 20, stream);
byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();

//Saving
String imageName = username + "_profile_picture.png";
final ParseFile file = new ParseFile(imageName, image);
file.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        if(e == null) {
            user.put("profilePicture", file);
            user.signUpInBackground();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using a image picker library that gets the path of the image. I then turn it into a bitmap.

Heres my code to retrieve the image:

```
ArrayList<Image> images = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(ImagePickerActivity.INTENT_EXTRA_SELECTED_IMAGES);
if(images.size() > 0) {
    Image image = images.get(0);
    File imgFile = new File(image.getPath());
    if(imgFile.exists()){
        profilePictureBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
        profilePictureImage.setImageBitmap(profilePictureBitmap);
    }
}
```

If there is any ideas on how to fix this I would greatly appreciate it.
Thanks :]

Comment: PNG does not use a lossy compression algorithm. Use JPEG for photos, such as a profile picture.

Comment: `a Bitmap which is taken from either the user's gallery or camera`. The camera app and the gallery app do not deliver bitmaps to begin with.

Comment: Alright I changed the compression algorithm to JPEG, but I'm still running into the same issue. The image won't compress.

Comment: You filled in `20` for which parameter? Look at its name. The bitmap is compressed to png or jpg but apparently you have a different idea about what compression is.

Comment: 20 is for the quality of the image. It should be 20% quality of the original image.

Comment: Indeed. So that is done. The quality is less. But you have something different in mind.

Comment: Shouldn't compression reduce the file size? I just want a image that is lower quality for the profile picture.

Comment: In my database the image stored is the exact same as the one pulled from my camera/gallery.

Comment: Bitmaps have no file size to begin with. You did not react on my comment concerning bitmaps. But save for 100, 50 and 10 percent and you will see that the file sizes becomes smaller. But then ... You want something else but you still did not reword what you really want.

Comment: I've tried 1% and 100% and the file size is the same when I download the file from my Parse database.

Comment: As you do not show how you put the saved files in a database we can not comment. Save to file first and you will see. But ..... You want something else.

Comment: What have downloaded files to do with  bitmap which you compress to file? Compress to file on your android and then have a look.

Comment: I included how I save the image into my database in the saving part of my code. All I'm trying to do is decrease the memory size of the image I'm storing in my database.

Comment: You will use far less memory by scaling the image down. Its a profile picture so it does not have to be big

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Image image = images.get(0);
File imgFile = new File(image.getPath());
if(imgFile.exists()){
    BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opts.inSampleSize = 2;  // one quarter of original size
    profilePictureBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath(), opts);
    profilePictureImage.setImageBitmap(profilePictureBitmap);
}
```

Docs for `inSampleSize`:

> If set to a value > 1, requests the decoder to subsample the original image, returning a smaller image to save memory. The sample size is the number of pixels in either dimension that correspond to a single pixel in the decoded bitmap. For example, inSampleSize == 4 returns an image that is 1/4 the width/height of the original, and 1/16 the number of pixels. Any value <= 1 is treated the same as 1. Note: the decoder uses a final value based on powers of 2, any other value will be rounded down to the nearest power of 2.